# Generate Objectivec C code from class diagram

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uml, code-generation, class-diagram

Do you know about some free tool which is able to generate Objective C code from class diagram? I am designing new iOS app right now and I want to create class diagram and would be helpful if I have some tool that will generate code from it.

Xcode does not event support class diagram modeling (this feature has been removed in Xcode 4 I think). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Visual paradigm generate Objective-C from UML class diagram. This is not a free tool, but they provide a 30 day trial option to the user. Other option is to use Free Code Generator for Astah, which is available to the Astah professional only.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will try them. It seems there is no such free a tool...

Answer (score 0):

There is [GenMyModel](https://www.genmymodel.com) as online alternative, it a UML modeler with code generation abilities. I don't think an ObjectiveC generator exists but you can code your own generator in Acceleo (there is an embedded code editor) and you can contact the team, they will kindly help you writing it.

Coding your own generator is hard but it ensure the generated code will be exactly as you want.

Comment: It provides generator only for Java, SQL and Spring. I do not think that Objective C generator exists as well so I just tried to ask here... Writing a code without generator is better than making own generator for my purpose. But thanks anyway